# How can I make a Div fully push another div offscreen?

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have 8 flexbox Div's (2columns, 4rows) how do I make it so when I press a button inside the Div it animates and pushes the other off screen whilst it expands right across?

I have currently been able to fully expand the div and hide the other one which looks ok (reason I hid it is because it ends up being about 5px wide on the left of the screen, but I've been working on this all day and just need to see how it's done!

CSS:

```
.col2 {
   flex: 1;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 5px;
   border:1px solid black;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: right;
}

.flex-grid {
   display: flex;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col2" id="box1"></div>
  <div class="col2" id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Tried lots of different jQuery animations but it just doesn't seem to move if it will take it off screen, even tried to do it just css with a push and expand class.

Really struggling so would appreciate any help!
(If you're wanting me to show the jQuery I've used to get the subpar solution of hiding the left element and expanding the right one across then let me know)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col2 {
   flex: 1;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 5px;
   border:1px solid black;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: right;
   
}

.flex-grid {
   display: flex;
}

#box1:hover {
  animation: 1s forwards;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {min-width: 0;}
  to {min-width: 99vw}
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col2" id="box1"></div>
  <div class="col2" id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

You need to add an animation to the given item (or generic), i.e.

```
#box1:hover {
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {min-width: 0;}
  to {min-width: 100vw}
}
```

Comment: That's great, really need it on click and not on hover though. Just out of it interest though, I tried the code and it works left to right but if I add another hover effect for right to left it has the same issue as my first try where it squashed the first div really narrow on the left margin, any idea why?

Comment: because elements in web grow from a starter position (x, y) => (0, 0) to (x, y) => (++x, ++y). This means it's growth axis is from left to right and from top to bottom.
Thus it's easy to push elements to the right but when looking for pushing them to the left you'll need to use an overflow: hidden to your wrapper and then instead making the element to grow in width (like in my example) you'll need to set a negative margin or absolute/fixed position which makes the left element move outside the layout to the left while increasing the size of the element on the right place. (is it clear?)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @JoelBonetR's answer to work with jQuery, you can use mouseover and mouseleave events to capture the hover event.

```js
$('.col2').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).css({
    'animation': '1s forwards',
    'background-color': 'red',
    'animation-name': 'example'
  });
  //hide other divs
  $(this).siblings().fadeOut();
});

$('.col2').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).css({
    'animation-name': 'none',
    'background-color': 'white'
  });
  //show other divs
  $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.col2 {
   flex: 1;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 5px;
   border:1px solid black;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: right;
   
}

.flex-grid {
   display: flex;
}



@keyframes example {
  from {min-width: 0;}
  to {min-width: 99vw}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col2" id="box1"></div>
  <div class="col2" id="box2"></div>
</div>
```